# Docker for Windows with Kubernetes and Windows Containers

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, docker-for-windows

Whenever switching to Windows Containers in Docker for windows, Kubernetes option is missing after restart.

[image]

I'm running windows 10 Enterprise.

Is is possible to create windows container (for .net framework app) and deploy kubernetes? Or are only linux containers supported on kubernetes (meaning only .net Standard/Core would work)?

Comment: I'm using MiniKube for that under Windows some details [here](https://learnk8s.io/blog/installing-docker-and-kubernetes-on-windows/)

Comment: but minikube ONLY supports linux containers..therefore your apps are only Core

Comment: Yes, sorry, my apps are .net core.

Comment: Does the problem still exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Windows nodes and containers on Kubernetes but the Kubernetes master (control plane) has to be Linux.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/

Similarly, you need to be running Windows Server 2019 for Kubernetes GA on Windows - Windows 10/Server 2016 is possible but it is considered beta